# Script that will allow users to post a comment to a URL's page with Disqus enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, disqus

Is it possible to create, for example, a PHP script that will allow users to post a comment to the web page of the other website with Disqus comments enabled, with the URL that inputted by the user?

1. Users will input the URL of the other website's page with Disqus comments enabled.
2. They will also input the comment that they want.
3. And the last is to submit.. *(Also, please provide the other required arguments that aren't listed here!)*

If it's possible, what are the procedures and the steps to achieve this kind of script?

> Actually, after contacting Disqus Support, they said this:
>
> You can post comments via our API. More information on our API can be found here: http://disqus.com/api

But I don't have a clue where can I start it, that's why I'm here..

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/

Comment: @ravipatel I'm not asking how to add a Disqus forum on my site. I'm asking about a script that will allow users to post a comment to the thread of any web page that have the URL that they've inputted.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you can do following steps;

**1.)** Get disqus php api library [here](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php)

**2.)** Register an application [here](http://disqus.com/api/applications/register/) and get `API Key` and `API Secret`

**3.)** Create form with minimal requirements;

```
<form action="comment_send.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c_name" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c_email" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thread ID: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c_thread_id" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comment: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="c_comment" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="create_comment" value="Create Comment"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**4.)** Write a handler for this form;

**comment_send.php**

```
require 'path/to/disqusapi.php';

$secret_key = API_SECRET;
$api_key = API_KEY;

$thread_id = $_POST["c_thread_id"]; // Url of the thread disqus enabled
$message = $_POST["c_comment"];
$author_name = $_POST["c_name"];
$author_email = $_POST["c_email"];

$disqus = new DisqusAPI($secret_key);
$res = $disqus->posts->create(array(
    'thread' => $thread_id,
    'message' => $message,
    'author_name' => $author_name,
    'author_email' => $author_email,
    'api_key' => $api_key,
));

echo "Comment send result: " . $res;
```

Comment: I want the script that will allow users to post to a comment to any blog *(I do not own this,)* that have Disqus comments enabled with any URL that have inputted by the users..

Comment: It is not necessary to have your own blog. `$thread_id` means url of the blog post that disqus enabled.

Comment: Not working: *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DisqusAPIError' with message 'Invalid argument, 'thread': Thread must be an integer, was 'http://professionalserver.tk/php/wp/hello-world/'' in /home/mbdungo/public_html/php/disqus-php-master/disqusapi/disqusapi.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /home/mbdungo/public_html/php/disqus-php-master/comment_send.php(19): DisqusResource->__call('create', Array) #1 /home/mbdungo/public_html/php/disqus-php-master/comment_send.php(19): DisqusResource->create(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/mbdungo/public_html/php/disqus-php-master/disqusapi/disqusapi.php on line 115*

Comment: Please try it in http://professionalserver.tk/php/disqus-php-master/comment.php .. As far as I know, the **thread** argument must have an integer thread ID, and we can pass the **link** query type instead of an ID only if we know and include the *'forum'* or *'shortname'* of the target website, that's why I've posted http://stackoverflow.com/q/22280824/2007055 ..